# Bootstrap3 Onclick button direct to new page

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, buttonclick

I have a problem here which I want to click button then go to another page. But it does not function

This is my code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-edit btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-editProfile" href="template/home.html">Start Booking Your Room</button>
```

I do not know why, the button does not function. 
please help me, I have wasted my whole day just doing this.

Thanks,
faizal

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

The plain HTML way is to put it in a `<form>` wherein you specify the desired target URL in the `action` attribute.

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>
```

Set if necessary CSS `display: inline;` on the form to keep it in the flow with the surrounding text.

### CSS

If CSS is allowed, simply use an `<a>` which you style to look like a button using among others the [`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) property ([only IE support is currently (July 2015) still poor](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)).

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="button">Go to Google</a>
```

```
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

Or pick one of those many CSS libraries like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

### JS

If JavaScript is allowed, set the `window.location.href`.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906586/408487)

Answer (score 0):

Buttons won't redirect you to another page unless you handle that in javascript. If you just want to redirect, you may use anchor tag, see example below:

```
<a class="btn btn-edit btn-sm pull-right" href="template/home.html">Start Booking Your Room</a>
```

Comment: I already do that, but it still return error "Object Not Found".

Comment: ok Sir.. Thank you soo much. <input class="btn btn-edit btn-sm pull-right" type="button" onclick="location.href='dashboard_totalticket.php';" value="Go to Google" />